# How to efficiently find out whether the user's current location is in the proximity of a lat long point?

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, firebase

I am thinking of building an Android application where people can drop down pins on an embeded Google Map in various locations. The condition for a user dropping a pin is that the pin must not be within a 100m radius of any other pin previously dropped. I am thinking of using firebase as a backend.

Looking up the distance between the location of the user and every pin on the map is not an efficient approach, since there may be thousands if not more dropped pins.

How would I go around solving this?

Comment: Look into [geohashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) would be a good match.

> GeoFire is set of open-source libraries for JavaScript, Objective-C,
>   and Java that allow you to store and query a set of keys based on
>   their geographic location. At its heart, GeoFire simply stores
>   locations with string keys. Its main benefit, however, is the
>   possibility of retrieving only those keys within a given geographic
>   area - all in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the `LatLng` points in a `HashSet` or a `HashMap` and then use the `LatLngBounds` class's `contains()` method to see if a certain region contains a point or not.

You can read more about it here: [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#contains(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng))